# Implementing Bootstrap Modal in Polymer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, polymer

I am trying to implement the Bootstrap Modal inside a Polymer-Element.  I have tried several approaches, but with little success.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around all of these new standards so I'm sure I am missing something.

What I would like

```
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo> 
</body>
```

Where x-foo has x-bar

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo" extends="div">
  <template>
    <x-bar></x-bar>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-foo', {
      // goodness
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="x-bar">
  <template>
    <style>
        .modal {
           // local style
        }
    </style>
    <div class="modal fade">
       <!-- ... rest of Bootstrap Modal tags / content -->
       <div id="awesome" on-click="awesome"></div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-bar',{
      ready : function() {
        window.$(this.$.modal).modal({show:false});
      },
      show : function() {
        window.$(this.$.modal).modal('show');
      },
      awesome : function() {
        alert('awesome');
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Now this works, kinda.  Calling show() on x-bar will show the popup, but the local styles will not show.  The styling not showing makes sense as the bootstrap.js as removed div.modal and attached it to main body.  But the click handler for the div.awesome never fires.

Now I have tried several variations all with similar results.  Note, am not tied to bootstrap Modal.  But I am interested in the best practice for implementing this tag and / or how to implement a custom popup that attaches to the main body for display (with all the web component goodness of course).

Comment: We have a `<polymer-ui-overlay>` [example][1] of that does a full page overlay. You can find a [demo here][2].

If you post a full jsbin and I'm happy to take a look at the Bootstrap example. It's probably do Shadow DOM encapsulation.


  [1]: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-ui-elements/blob/stable/polymer-ui-overlay/polymer-ui-overlay.html
  [2]: http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer-all/polymer-ui-elements/polymer-ui-overlay/index.html

Comment: This looks great!  Thanks!  And sorry, obviously did not dig deep enough into the element demo's.  Though quick question, viewing the source, dialog2 is what I hope to accomplish but I'm getting 'Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: Object #<HTMLUnknownElement> has no method 'show''  when I try to show it.  I'm on chrome v30.0.1581.2 (Pixel in dev mode).  Thoughts?

Comment: That element in particular is going through a bunch of changes. We just updated it yesterday. If you try it now, does it work?

Comment: Yup, like a charm.  Assumed that was the case. *Side question, you guys prefer questions here or in the google group?